# How to show download progress in progressbar? Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, timer, progress-bar, backgroundworker, webclient

im so confused because this code didn't work. It downloaded the file successfully but don't report the progress to the `ProgressBar`. I already started `Timer1` using `Timer1.Start()` before `BackgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync()`  .

```
Dim size As Double
Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.DoWork
    Try
        Dim G As Integer = 150
        Dim Increase As Boolean = True
        Do Until Clicked = True
            If Increase = True Then
                If Not G = 255 Then
                    G += 1
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
                Else
                    Increase = False
                End If
            Else
                If Not G = 150 Then
                    G -= 1
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
                Else
                    Increase = True
                End If
            End If
            Label6.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, G, 0)
        Loop
        Label6.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        Label6.Text = "Initializing"
        Label6.ForeColor = Color.Lime
        MessageBox.Show("Description :" & Environment.NewLine & Description & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "Total Size: " & Environment.NewLine & TotalSize & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "Download Link (Global): " & Environment.NewLine & DownlaodLink, "BIOS Update Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        'WebBrowser1.Navigate(DownlaodLink)
        'BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        size = TotalSize.Replace(" MBytes", "")
        Me.Refresh()
        Dim wc As New WebClient
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(DownlaodLink), My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\A55BM-E BIOS " & LatestVersion.ToString.Replace(" ", "") & ".zip")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

And the code to show me the progress of my download

```
Dim cursize As Double
Dim finsize As Double
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If System.IO.File.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\A55BM-E BIOS " & LatestVersion.ToString.Replace(" ", "") & ".zip") Then
        cursize = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\A55BM-E BIOS " & LatestVersion.ToString.Replace(" ", "") & ".zip").Length
        finsize = cursize / size * 100

        If Not ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
            ProgressBar1.Value = finsize
            ProgressBar1.Refresh()
        Else
            ProgressBar1.Value = finsize
            ProgressBar1.Refresh()
            Timer1.Stop()
            MsgBox("Finished Downloading")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I can't figure out how to make this work. Can someone help me?

Comment: From MSDN: *You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged [...] event.*  Turn on Option Strict and study [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: Opps, forgot about that! Thanks for reminding me lol!

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer if it worked. It helps future readers to identify the working answer faster. Also it shows to the community that this question has been solved and they don't need to put some effort to solve the problem and they can focus on un-answered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally! I made it work but didn't go with the `BackgroundWorker`. The code below is what I've used to make this thing work. And it's so efficient and easy to use too.

```
Public WithEvents downloader As WebClient

Public Sub DownloadStart()
    Label6.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Label6.Text = "Initializing"
    Label6.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    MessageBox.Show("Description :" & Environment.NewLine & Description & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "Total Size: " & Environment.NewLine & TotalSize & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "Download Link (Global): " & Environment.NewLine & DownlaodLink, "BIOS Update Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    ProgressBar1.Visible = True
    downloader = New WebClient
    downloader.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(DownlaodLink), My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\A55BM-E BIOS " & LatestVersion.ToString.Replace(" ", "") & ".zip")
End Sub

Private Sub downloader_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles downloader.DownloadProgressChanged
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
```

Thanks everyone for helping me!